# Why I can't import Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I followed the Flask instructions and I successfully installed Flask by using Command Prompt.

```
C:\Users\DELL>py -3 -m pip install flask
```

> C:\Users\DELL>py -3 -m pip install flask
> Requirement already satisfied: flask in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.1.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from flask) (1.1.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from flask) (2.11.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from flask) (1.0.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from flask) (7.1.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask) (1.1.1)

However when I use PyCharm to import flask, it doesn't recognize flask.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Comment: Could you add your code ?

Comment: it just simply: from flask import Flask, but it doesn't recognize it as a module.

Comment: try this ```python -c "from flask import Flask as f; print(f.__version__)"```

Answer (score 0):

The most probable problem is `py` command is related with `python2` and `flask` module is installed in your `python3` site-packages. So try to execute explicitly with `python3` as :

```
python3 app.py
```